# c2027 use of undefined type “v8::internal::Object"

Tags: c++, v8, visual-studio-2019

i'm trying to build google v8 using visual studio 2019(i'm able to build using official steps with clang), and got below error:

Error C2027 use of undefined type “v8::internal::Object" v8_base_without_compiler [E:\v8\src\handles\handles.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/handles/handles.h) 144

```
  V8_INLINE T operator*() const {
    // unchecked_cast because we rather trust Handle<T> to contain a T than
    // include all the respective -inl.h headers for SLOW_DCHECKs.
    SLOW_DCHECK(IsDereferenceAllowed(INCLUDE_DEFERRED_CHECK));
    return T::unchecked_cast(Object(*location()));  // error on this line
  }
```

my understanding of this part is, [handles.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/handles/handles.h) includes [objects.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/objects.h) and has forward declaration for class `Object` (from objects.h), and inline operator method is calling `Object` constructor, which leads to c2027 use of undefined type `v8::internal::Object`

i created a [simple c++ project](https://github.com/cjbd/pp/) with visual studio 2019 to reproduce the same error message

[handles.h](https://github.com/cjbd/pp/blob/master/pp/handles.h)

```
#ifndef HANDLES_H_
#define HANDLES_H_

// forward declaration
class Object;

class Handle {
public:
    __forceinline void* op() {
        return new Object(0); // error here c2027 use of undefined type "Object"
    }

    void dummy();
};

#endif
```

[objects.h](https://github.com/cjbd/pp/blob/master/pp/objects.h)

```
#ifndef OBJECTS_H_
#define OBJECTS_H_

class Object {
public:
    explicit Object(int n):_n(n) {

    }

    void dummy();

    int _n;
};

#endif
```

which is similar logic, an inline method implementation calls another class constructor

i don't understand how google's official steps with `gn` and `clang` could compile through the whole project, but msvc errors out

how to make it work for visual studio 2019? thanks!

Comment: How about including the header of your object?

Comment: @JVApen, thanks a lot, it works for both my sample project and v8 code using msvc. although the v8 code might have indirectly included the objects.h from other header files, i'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying @JVApen's comment as answer

add `#include "ojbects.h"` will fix the issue

and if you're trying to build google's v8 using visual studio 2019, add `#include "objects/objects.h"` in `handles/handles.h`, then it will compile through